# Javascript storing first value from foreach php function and keep repeating it

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript file that doing encoding for some string and implement it inside `foreach` PHP function to get values but unfortunately javascript holding and storing the first value from the `foreach` function only and keep repeating it

**PHP**

```
foreach ($json_content as $index => $array) {
        echo '<textarea id="index" style="display:none">'.$index.'</textarea>';
        echo '<textarea id="encoded'.$index.'" style="display:none">'.$aa_encode.'</textarea>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="decdoe.js"></script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">function();</script>';
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var index    = document.getElementById("index");
var AEncoded = document.getElementById("encoded"+index.value);
document.write(index.value);
document.write(function(AEncoded.value));
```

**Output**

```
000
firstvalue/firstvalue/firstvalue
```

What I missed?

Comment: ID should be unique in the HTML. You have it set so you have multiple called "index", chances are, the JS only ever notes the first one it sees.

Comment: It is unique, that's why I added `$index` beside the ID

Comment: `id="index"` is not unique. It's duplicated.

Comment: You are correct, I changed it to `id="index'.$index.'"` but it gave me this error `Uncaught TypeError: index is null` in console log

Comment: How to pass/send the index number to javascript file?

Comment: You could use a counter and a loop in the JS I guess. Add a unique element with the number of indicies, then loop from 0 to that number in your JS, using getElementById on indexX.

Comment: I am really new to Javascript world, May you give me small example for Javascript counter

Comment: My JS is a little too rusty to attempt, but by counter I just mean a variable starting at 0 that you add 1 to for each iteration of a loop.

Comment: I did it but now the PHP print the output 3 times in each echo `firstvalue/secondvalue/thirdvalue
firstvalue/secondvalue/thirdvalue
firstvalue/secondvalue/thirdvalue`

Comment: I fixed, Thanks for helping @Jonnix

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

First: I added the ID inside a loop in the Javascript file like this

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < $numberofloops ; i++) {
   var AEncoded = document.getElementById("encoded"+[i]);
}
```

Then pulled out the function call from the `foreach` PHP

```
foreach ($json_content as $index => $array) {
        rest of code here
}
echo '<script type="text/javascript">function();</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

if all you need to do is store every $index into a textarea and save it into a java var, then try throwing a while look on every case of echo that you need all variables from...
so for example, you would put a code like this:

```
 while($index = value){
 echo $index
 }
```

inside of your #index textarea then grab that textarea's value with java

Comment: I did it but now the PHP print the output 3 times in each echo `firstvalue/secondvalue/thirdvalue firstvalue/secondvalue/thirdvalue firstvalue/secondvalue/thirdvalue`